# Set the values of hidden fields though C# Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I am trying to set the values of 2 hidden fields with C# code. These feilds will hold an error message and exception.

The process run is to download a valuation file and run some other code.

This process returns the percentage of the process and so is done with threads.

As this is done with threads when i get an error i can't Redirect to action to my error page.
So i would like to add my error message to the hidden field's and then display them on my error page.

I have tried using TempDate[] and session[] but they keep returning null once i navigate to my error page.

So if i could set the error message to the hidden fields then pull them of the hidden fields once navigated to the error page that would be great.

Could someone please tell me how i could do this?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="exceptionName" value="IOExceptionn">`. However, you can't write binary data or complex objects in such way without using of serialization/deserialization

Comment: I have build to hidden fields in my layout page already, so they will be available on all my pages, i would just like to know how to write to them from inside my controller. I will be writing two string two them.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="exceptionName" value="@(ViewBag.ExceptionName as string)" />` or smth like this. Then from controller code you can write `ViewBag.ExceptionName = "IOException"`

Comment: @nsinreal, Ok i see where you going with this, yeah let me give it a shot.

Comment: sorry, my English sucks. Can you explain your sentence in other words?

Comment: I said, i understand what you are trying to do, so i'm going to try and see if it works :)